# HomeKit HMHome Users deprecated iOS9

Tags: ios, homekit

In iOS8 HMHome had access to users, this does not work in iOS9, how do you know which users the home was shared with in iOS9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't.  The only available information is the access control the user has to the home, whether he/she is an administrator of the home or is a guest of a home (shared). Apple controls the list of users with its own dialog.

You use this function to show Apple dialog

```
manageUsersWithCompletionHandler(_: (NSError?) -> Void)
```

where you can check the access the user has with this HMHome extension

```
var isAdmin: Bool {
    return self.homeAccessControlForUser(currentUser).administrator
}
```